# Using Node.dll binary to execute JS in Win32

Tags: node.js, winapi

As the title says, I would like to run a JS file from within my application. I dont want to create a node.exe process. Is there any sample example to start with?

Edit:
I plan to use standalone dll that comes with electron installer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-installer-windows 
or build it myself using electron instructions

Comment: *from within my application* - what application? What did make you think there's such thing as node.dll? See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23265

Comment: electron installer comes with a standalone dll - https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-installer-windows

Comment: I'm not sure at all that it can be used apart from Electron. But you can try to extract it and check Electron sources on how to use it. Any way, that's Electon's own build. There's no official build. There's no official way to do this. See the link above, e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23265#issuecomment-429076703 .

Comment: If this is not possible I would like to build it myself.. Electron has a blog article for this: https://electronjs.org/blog/electron-internals-using-node-as-a-library But I wanted to know if anyone attempted or ran into problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need run JavaScript in a Windows app, you can use [ActiveScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349554/Cplusplus-Win32-and-Scripting-Quick-way-to-add-Scr) instead.

Otherwise this doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: Executing pure JS code is not difficult. But nodejs env and bindings can do lot more

Comment: If you are in Windows, you can do a lot more anyway than using plain Javascript.